# Kibana Status: Red

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am setting up my Elasticsearch and kibana using the steps provided in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04 
Everything is up , but kibana page is showing status red and showing elasticsearch plugin as service unavailable. I have given network.host in elastic search as localhost, also tried with 0.0.0.0, but no luck. Kindly help on what i am missing here.

Comment: What do you see in the kibana log? It usually means that ES is either not started or unreachable. What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200` on your server?

Comment: Kibana.stdout log does not have any status about ES. I am unable to paste the log. It is too log.

Comment: You can update your question with the relevant part of your kibana log. What does the curl command give you?

Comment: {
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 503,
  "name" : "Mother Superior",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.7",
    "build_hash" : "36897d07dadcb70886db7f149e645ed3d44eb5f2",
    "build_timestamp" : "2013-11-13T12:06:54Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"

Comment: `status:503` does not sound good

Comment: sorry , i changed network.host to 0.0.0.0 before taking that output, If network.host to localhost the output is : {
  "name" : "Kamuu",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.3",
    "build_hash" : "218bdf10790eef486ff2c41a3df5cfa32dadcfde",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-05-17T15:40:04Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Then you need to make sure that your Kibana config points to localhost:9200 as well.

Comment: if i untag this part of the config file elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200" , Kibana service is not starting up

Comment: You should edit your question with both configuration files (from kibana and elasticsearch), we won't be able to help you much without more information